# The "order by" in a function in postgresql is reversed when called slightly different

Tags: postgresql, sorting, ubuntu-18.04

I have a function that select from a table where transactions are stored. The function is longer so I have made a terse version to try to illustrate the issue I have. The original function have a "union all" to get total sum, sum by division and finally by product which I have left out. The output is converted to a PDF-file. The behaviour I see does not seem to be caused by the function itself but when I call the function in two ways.

I join a customer table using a organisation-id. Some customers are registered more than once with the same organisation-id but different customer-ids. There are reasons beyond my control why a customer can be registered more than once. So in order not to get duplicate lines I made an exemption-table for these cases.

I then "order by" using a case since I need to display the products in a specific order. With the first call the products are sorted as desired but the latter the sort is reversed.

This is on ubuntu 18.04 LTS and postgresql 10.12.

```
create or replace function f(quarter integer, year integer, cid text)
  returns table (cid text, name text, product text, quantity numeric, vat text, amount numeric)
as
$body$
select
 cid,
 name,
 internal_product,
 sum(quantity) as quantity,
 vat,
 sum(amount) as amount
from transaction
where
 extract('quarter' from created_at) = $1 and extract('year' from created_at) = $2
group by
 cid,
 name,
 internal_product,
 vat) as VAT

where cid in ($3)

order by
 name desc,
 case internal_product
  when 'product A' then 1
  when 'extra B' then 2
  when 'large C' then 3
  when 'small D' then 4
  when '' then 99
 end
 $body$
language sql;
```

This sorts the way I want.

```
select
 c.cid, c.cidtext, f.*
from
 f(2,2020,'958935420') f
join
 customer c
on
 f.cid = c.cid;
```

Adding the exemption table reverses the sort.

```
select
 c.cid, c.cidtext, f.*
from
 f(2,2020,'958935420') f
join
 customer c
on
 f.cid = c.cid
where c.cid not in (select cid from exempt_cid);
```

Comment: afaik, if your final query doesn't sort, then you have no defined sort order, even if inner queries did sort. looks like a dupe of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130552/in-postgresql-is-the-row-ordering-preserved-in-functions-and-ctes - so, in other words, you should sort at the final query (or in the UI), not at inner queries that get called along the way.

Comment: I agree with @underscore_d.  If you want to keep your `case` statement in the function for convenience, then add `row_number() over (order by . . .) as sort_key` and then you can `order by sort_key` in your final query.

Comment: Thank you. I'll move the sort to the final query and test. The first query in my question is a result of two similar queries I created. And when the third similar query came along I made it into a function. Reused most, and moved on. :-)

Comment: @underscore_d Your comment pointed me in the right direction. The last query shall perform the sort, which is obvious in hindsigt. :-) I call this from a spring boot app and to keep that query terse I will make a second function that calls the first function. If you wish you can formulate an answer which I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `SELECT` statement only has a definite ordering if it has an `ORDER BY` clause. Since the statement that calls the function doesn't have `ORDER BY`, you don't have that guarantee.

In practice, it will depend on the execution plan (use `EXPLAIN`). The function itself will return values in the desired order, and if there is nothing in the rest of the execution plan that disturbs that order, you are fine.

My advice is **never** to add an `ORDER BY` clause to a view definition or a function result, but always have it where it belongs, in the calling query. PostgreSQL doesn't optimize such `ORDER BY` clauses, and you may end up paying the price of a sort without having any benefit.

Comment: Thank you. True, added the sort to the final query now. The function is a result of two similar queries that I made into a function when the third came along. And reused most and it worked (apart from the sorting). I'll change the queries and just use sorting in the last.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ordering in the function to simplify code maintenance in case the ordering has to change in the future and you do not want to update multiple calling queries:

```
create or replace function f(quarter integer, year integer, cid text)
  returns table (cid text, name text, product text, quantity numeric, vat text, amount numeric)
as
$body$
select
 cid,
 name,
 internal_product,
 sum(quantity) as quantity,
 vat,
 sum(amount) as amount,
 row_number() 
    over (order by name desc,
                   case internal_product
                     when 'product A' then 1
                     when 'extra B' then 2
                     when 'large C' then 3
                     when 'small D' then 4
                     when '' then 99
                   end) as sort_key
from transaction
where
 extract('quarter' from created_at) = $1 and extract('year' from created_at) = $2
group by
 cid,
 name,
 internal_product,
 vat) as VAT

where cid in ($3)
 
 $body$
language sql;
```

Then your calls would look like this:

```
select
 c.cid, c.cidtext, f.cid, f.name, f.internal_product, f.quantity, f.vat, f.amount
from
 f(2,2020,'958935420') f
join
 customer c
on
 f.cid = c.cid
order by sort_key;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll move the sort to the last query as suggested since I need to sort by unit in a company in addition to the product name to show what each unit have used.

Comment: @kometen Then you can `order by unit_name, sort_key` in your outer query.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that.